# How pass a td value from html template to my views.py

Tags: django

Am fairly new to django, so trying to play around with django and learn at the same time by building a small project.

Basically I have the below code in my html template:

```
                  <tbody>
                  {% for items in queries %}
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ items.ana_user }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ items.ana_public }}</t>
                    <td>{{ items.ana_private }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ items.ana_bytestx }} MB</t>
                    <td>{{ items.ana_bytesrx }} MB</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ items.ana_policy }}</t>
                    <td>{{ items.ana_duration }}</td>
                    <td class="btn-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Options
                  </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'stats' %}">View Live Graph</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'disconnect' %}">Disconnect Users</a>
                  </div>
               </td>
             </tr>
           {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Basically by clicking any of the dropdown action. I want to take the value of the first td which is 'items.ana_user' and pass this to my views.py as a 'request.POST.get'.

Your help is very much appreciated as usual.

Comment: You would need to use Django Forms to create a POST.  That said,  the `queries` variable you are looping through is already coming from a view.  So technically, it's already there.  I'm guessing you have a variable in your view called queries.  The information in that is the same thing that is getting rendered to the template.

Comment: Basically all those values are from a database which is being sent as a context (queries) to the template. Those values are dynamic and its difficult to get a specific value directly from views.py(Well that I can think of). So by creating a dropdownmenu button in the table. I will be able to get the exact value and have the option of either disconnect or view live graph which are in different views in my views.py.

Comment: Oh I see, if your `stats` view and `disconnect` view take variables, then in the {% url 'stats' %} you would pass the `items.ana_user` like this (same for `disconnect`) `{% url 'stats' items.ana_user %}`  This is how you pass data in a url in Django.